# Fear of planets

Tags: mental-health, terminology, reference-request, phobia

When I was in preschool, I saw a 3D space adventure movie and almost cried. I don't know why but I get so scared when I see a planet. They are just very creepy to me. Even looking at a planet in a book scares me. is there a name for this fear? Are there any documented cases of it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm scared of certain celestial objects](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/11710/im-scared-of-certain-celestial-objects)